# crontab shell not executing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have a shell that opens a terminal

```
terminator -l terminalName
```

it executes just fine when i do it manually, but i'm trying to execute it in crontab -e and it just doesn't executes.

i want to execute the shell at startup (@reboot etc)
but i'm also trying

```
* * * * * /path/to/shell/shell.sh
```

and it also doesn't executes

journalctl says:

```
Jun 07 15:47:01 juanowl CRON[28804]: (juanowl) CMD (sh /home/juanowl/SHELLS_DOCUMENTATION/UTILS/STARTUP_TERMINAL/STARTUP_TERMINAL.sh)
Jun 07 15:47:01 juanowl CRON[28803]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 07 15:47:01 juanowl CRON[28803]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user juanowl
```

Comment: Redirect stdout and stderr to a file so you can see the error messages.

Comment: X requires the `DISPLAY` environment variable to know where to display windows. This variable isn't set when running from `cron`, so you need to set it explictly.

Comment: Running interactive applications from `cron` is a strange thing to do, though. What should it do when there's no one logged in?

Comment: How do you login after the machine starts? Why not just add your script to run during the session startup?

Comment: AND ...  running `* * * * * /path/to/shell.sh` will try to start that application 60 time per hour, 24 hrs a day, 7 days a week. Unless the script can kill it competitors, you'll overwhelm your system in a short amount of time. I believe newer `crron` systems support `on boot` or something that will only launch one version. `man cron`, `man crontab` hopefully can help you. Good luck.

Comment: This is nothing that should get done using `cron`. Sounds like something that belongs into the "autostart" mechanism of your environment, whatever that is.